# Offset / Outline stroke apply to QML Text element

Tags: qt, qml

I am trying to apply offset or stroke effect to 'Text' element in QML. However, there is no border.width property or color in Text element. Does anyone know what will be the best approach?

Ideally, I want something like:

[image]

Thank you@

Comment: Check https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-text.html#style-prop, `Text { style: Text.Outline; styleColor: "red" }`.

Comment: @SMR you should turn it into an answer so I can upvote.

Comment: @StephenQuan, Thanks, I think it is unnecessary. Please include it in your answer.

Comment: @SMR I couldn't do that. I never thought to check the documentation for such a property.

Comment: OMG...I feel I just asked a very stupid question because previously I did not use the Text.Outline in right way and it gave me error which made thought this wont work in Qt 5......Thank you so much! @SMR

Answer (score 1):

[EDIT] I just saw SMR's comment. It's way better than this answer!

The old school approach is to draw to create 9 instances of the text in background color and paint it at x: -1 .. 1 and y: -1 .. 1. Then you draw the final text instance in the foreground color on top:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Page {
    Frame {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        background: Rectangle {
            color: "#ccc"
        }
        OutlineText {
            text: "65%"
            font.pointSize: 70
            color: "white"
            outlineColor: "black"
        }
    }
}

// OutlineText.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls

Label {
    text: "ABC"
    color: "white"
    font.pointSize: 70
    property color outlineColor: "black"
    Repeater {
        model: 9
        Label {
            x: index % 3 - 1
            y: Math.floor(index / 3) - 1
            text: parent.text
            font.pointSize: parent.font.pointSize
            font.family: parent.font.family
            color: outlineColor
            z: -2
        }
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAADF3icfVJRT8IwEH7vr7hgSPSBoRI19k1JTEw0CvoHuu4GDV1vlhIBw3+3pGNZN+Cert993+67u6miJOtg4iYrJRdMRc9kTMZZ0kv2KWYIfwx8vFhRHPJ9CCPnZJeJROPQvhoOpbA+rwmpkIuZpZXJOExROmFmuvmBfUjSZDn0LqSUvbqyq7OPldPK4DeuXUvpPOSF93f9XoTn3npSkjLuS22Rw8P10Ya/c+UwVlLoNa4Yqfb+2552bMfYcNj0lfwUurW/k+tkbyJFXU1STfD0PA5djlg7MUxpqUTrNkFyxvgUSxT+Oo3dFZSh5vBYA01Lh1hzUCbDNfRhBAO4iYobDu/CzZNcE9nLwBvC6KpDDAOGvyLZP84equLFcFeRi0LpTUwP2LE7N1cT1bccBrfd4/4D7ZnZOg==)

Comment: Hi Stephen, although I used @SMR answer but this one also works. Thank you so much!!

Comment: @SMR answer is the best! :-)